# Issue when asking about products with upfront_fare_enabled

Tags: uber-api

Asking about all products, returns list with "upfront_fare_enabled" field. When asking about single product, "upfront_fare_enabled" field is "inverted". Take a look at example:

`curl -H 'Authorization: Token xxx' 'https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1.2/products?latitude=40.7413129&longitude=-73.9831658'`

It returns (response is trimmed):

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "upfront_fare_enabled": false,
      "product_id": "1508c51e-339a-4b91-b32a-a7d5e781e4c2",
      "display_name": "uberPOOL"
    },
    {
      "upfront_fare_enabled": true,
      "product_id": "b8e5c464-5de2-4539-a35a-986d6e58f186",
      "display_name": "uberX"
    }
  ]
}
```

But when I ask about product with id = 1508c51e-339a-4b91-b32a-a7d5e781e4c2 where upfront_fare_enabled was `false`, it will return `upfront_fare_enabled=true`.

```
curl -H 'Authorization: Token xxx' 'https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1.2/products/1508c51e-339a-4b91-b32a-a7d5e781e4c2'
{
  "upfront_fare_enabled": true,
  "product_id": "1508c51e-339a-4b91-b32a-a7d5e781e4c2",
  "display_name": "uberPOOL"
}
```

Is this expected behavior? Seems like a bug in API to me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing your findings - we will review `GET /v1.2/products/{product_id}` endpoint. To get an upfront fare through '[POST /v1.2/requests/estimate](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/requests-estimate-post#example-response-with-upfront-fares)' please use info of the 'upfront_fare_enabled' by looking at [GET /v1.2/products](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/products-get) to see which products are enabled for Upfront Fare. If the product is not enabled for upfront fees you will get the response like: 

'{
  "message": "Invalid product \"1508c51e-339a-4b91-b32a-a7d5e781e4c2\". Available: 0e9d8dd3-xxx",
  "code": "not_found"
}'

You can also read the best practices on Upfront Fares [here](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/api/best-practices#upfront-fares).